# Error doesn't show where it is (Field list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.)

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I contribute to a project that uses *sphinx* as a documentation engine. We're trying to remove all of the warnings, but we have 8 warnings of the same type yet as you can see in the output below:

```
WARNING: :1: (WARNING/2) Field list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
...
WARNING: :1: (WARNING/2) Field list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
```

The warnings have no clues where they're and I can't find the root of the problem!
I tried to use `--trace` and `--debug` flags, but nothing new and important was printed out!

**Environment info**

- Python version: 3.8.3
- Sphinx version: 3.2.1
- Sphinx extensions:

```
sphinx.ext.autodoc
sphinx.ext.doctest
sphinx.ext.todo
sphinx.ext.coverage
sphinx.ext.viewcode
sphinx.ext.autosummary
sphinx.ext.napoleon
m2r
sphinx_autodoc_typehints
sphinxcontrib.mermaid
hoverxref.extension
```

Comment: The clue is in the error: "field list". Searching Sphinx docs turns up this hit: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/field-lists.html#file-wide-metadata. A field list can appear below a directive, such as `toctree`. White space has meaning in Sphinx, so make sure that you use proper and consistent indentation.

Comment: There are three other questions about this warning: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Field+list+ends+without+a+blank+line%22

Comment: @StevePiercy I found one, but the code seems correct!! The file are [here](https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/master/docs/pages/result.rst), if I remove the `:members` from `automodule` works correctly. But does not make sense if we're following the sphinx guide!

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. When trying to solve these types of issues, I comment out or delete content until the warning goes away. Then I know that the problem is in that content, and I continue the process until I find the problem.

Comment: @StevePiercy I've found a bug, it's very specific. I already have opened an [issue](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8190) for sphinx.